# Converting Hexadecimal string to int

Tags: c

Write a C function, that accepts a null-terminated string, containing a hexadecimal string, and returns the integer value. You cannot call any C library function, except strlen() to code the function. The decimal string will only contain 0-4 ASCII characters from ‘0’ through ‘9’ and ‘A’ through ‘F’. No error handling is required. If the string is empty, then return a value of 0.

I've constantly tried fixing my errors, but once I fix them, new errors pop up, resulting in me being confused.

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /*used for EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <stdio.h>   /*used for printf */
#include <string.h>  /* used for strlen */
#include <stdbool.h> /* used for bool */
#include <math.h>


unsigned int hexStringTouint(const char str[], int length, int n[])
{
    int i, j;
    int intvalue = 0;
    int digit;
    for(i = (length-1), j = 0; i --, j++)
    {
        if(n[i]>='0' && n[i] <='9')
        {
            digit = n[i] - 0x30;
        }
        else if(n[i]>= 'A' && n[i] <= 'F')
        {
            switch(n[i])
            {
                case 'A': digit = 10; break;
                case 'B': digit = 11; break;
                case 'C': digit = 12; break;
                case 'D': digit = 13; break;
                case 'E': digit = 14; break;
                case 'F': digit = 15; break;
            }
        }
        intvalue += digit*pow(16,j);
    }
    printf("int value is %d\n", intvalue);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, length, intvalue;
    unsigned char n[] = "";
    printf("Enter your hexadecimal string: ");
    scanf("%c\n", n);
    intvalue = 0;
    length = strlen(n);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am getting error messages saying 
`expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier` 
and how const char* converts between pointers and integers.

Comment: for needs 3 statements. you missed the condition to break the loop. it should be `for(i = (length-1), j = 0; i >= 0; i --, j++)` in your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C code to convert hex to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951714/c-code-to-convert-hex-to-int)

Comment: don't use `pow(16,j)`. Use `1 << j*4` instead

Comment: A hint: If `char c` is the variable with current hexdigit character: The values of digits `'0'` to `'9'` are `c - '0'`. Similar, the values of digits `'A'` to `'F'` are `c - 'A' + 0xa`. Usually, upper case letters are accepted as well as lower case letters. In this case, a `toupper(c)` wouldn't hurt. (It doesn't change any non-alpha character.) Altogether: `if (isxdigit(c)) digit = isdigit(c) ? c - '0' : toupper(c) - 'A' + 0xa;` - a one liner... ;-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7084213/694576

Comment: @Scheff Corner cases: `isdigit(c), toupper(c)` are UB when `c < 0` and not `EOF` and misses the goal "cannot call any C library function"

Comment: If you want to subtract a `'0'` from `n[i]`, use `'0'` rather than `0x30` -->  `digit = n[i] - '0';`

Comment: @chux Sigh. I know. (This was not fully production ready code.) ;-) I missed the part with _cannot call any C library function_. Though, with a bit luck, `isdigit()` and friends are macros (like here [ctype.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/include/safe-ctype.h)).

Comment: @Scheff [ctype.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/include/safe-ctype.h) looks amiss when arg is `EOF`.  Example, I'd expect `tolower(EOF)` to return `EOF`.  Hmmm.

Comment: @chux Hmmm. I've never thought about this. (Usually, I stop character processing when `EOF` is received.) Though, it seems to work at least in gcc 8.2: [**tolower(EOF) on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5a5cc9971e38550). I saw this `#define TOLOWER(c) _sch_tolower[(c) & 0xff]` and got the idea it might work (surprisingly, as I already stumbled into the signed char issue in VC++ in the past...)

Comment: @chux Your comment inspired me to think a little bit more about `EOF`: [more tolower(EOF) on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/651b60bc25b0d257). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Much of OP's code is the right track, yet various coding errors exist.

**Add test condition**

```
// for(i = (length-1), j = 0; i --, j++)
//                         v 
for(i = (length-1), j = 0; i >= 0; i --, j++)
```

**cannot call any C library function, except strlen()**

```
// intvalue += digit*pow(16,j);
intvalue += digit*(1u << (4*j));
```

**Return the value**

Requirement "... and returns the integer value"

```
//int intvalue = 0;
//...
//printf("int value is %d\n", intvalue);
//return 0;

unsigned intvalue = 0;
...
printf("integer value is %u\n", intvalue);
return intvalue;
```

**Buffer too small**

```
// unsigned char n[] = "";
// scanf("%c\n", n);

char n[100] = "";
scanf("%99s", n);
```

**hexStringTouint()**

Function not called in `main()`.

**Other issues  exist**

---

A *simpler* approach

```
unsigned hexStringTouint2(const char *str) {
  unsigned value = 0;
  while (*str) {
    unsigned digit = hexCharTouint(*str);  // tbd code
    value = value*16 + digit;
    str++;
  }
  return value;
}
```